# How to determine if the directed graph is a strongly connected graph or not by using BFS algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory, data-structure

I have the following directed graph:

[image]

**I was trying to determine if the above graph is a strongly connected graph or not**.
I read in few communities that you can do this by following the steps below:

1. Take the **BFS** or **DFS** of the original graph.
2. Take a ***transpose*** of the original graph.
3. Take the **BFS** or **DFS** of the ***transpose***.
4. If all the vertices from original graph were covered in both steps **1** & **3** then one can conclude that the graph is a **strongly connected graph**.

To solve this, I took the **BFS** of the original graph which gives me the output: **0 2 1 3 4**

Then I reversed the edges of the original graph to get the ***transpose***:

[image]

This is where I'm stuck. I have a few doubts here:

1. What is the **BFS** of this ***transpose***? I'm stuck at the output: **0 1 2**. Is this correct?
2. Can I conclude that the original graph is a **weakly connected graph**?
3. Can **weakly connected graphs** contain **strongly connected components**?

---

***P.S: I've gone through the theories but can't seem to figure this out. Any help with examples would be much appreciated.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is (assuming you start in 0, 1 or 2) - other vertices are unreachable from them. By the way, to make sure your algorithm for strong connectivity is correct, you have to start both BFS from the same vertex.
2. Yes, you can, because from first step you know that you can reach all vertices from vertex 0 even without traveling in reverse. Note that converse isn't true - even if both BFSes didn't visit all vertices, graph can still be weakly connected.
3. Of course. Any graph is disjoint union of strongly connected components.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I'm fine with your answers to point 1. & 3. Could you elaborate what you meant by "even if both BFSes didn't visit all vertices, graph can still be strongly connected.". Does it mean that if both BFS's traversed the same half amount of vertices from the original graph then the original graph is strongly connected graph?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I meant "weakly". Assume graph is 0 -> 1 <- 2 -> 3. This graph is weakly connected, but BFS from any vertex both on it and on it's transpose don't visit all vertices. If graph is **strongly** connected, then BFS from any vertex both on it and it's transpose will visit all vertices.

Comment: I think this statement just confused me. What did you mean by "even if both BFS's didn't"? Can I just assume that if all vertices are visited by both BFS's then it's a strongly connected graph else its a weakly connected graph?

Comment: First yes, second no. There are also not connected at all graphs, and BFS will not visit all vertices on them too.

Comment: Thank you! Sir.